# Unknown error in a state in react when trying to change it

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently learning react and I receive an unknown error when trying to create a function that changes the state of a class component and render the value. The button does not display the state value and the function gives an unknown error. How do I fix it?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            loggedIn:true
        }
    }
    render(){
      const Log = () =>{
            this.setState({loggedIn:!loggedIn})
            }
    return (
        <div>
<button onClick={Log}>{this.state.loggedIn}</button>
        </div>
    )
    }
}

export default App
```

[image: Browser]
[image: Console]

Comment: `const Log ` should be outside render method

Comment: Why? Shouldn't display logic be inside of the display method. When moving the Log function outside, react sees const as random characters, and when I remove const it says that the function is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using setState() inside of render() is a malpractice.**

> Calling setState() here makes your component producing infinite loops. The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser. In this case, avoid using setState() here.

https://blog.logrocket.com/an-imperative-guide-to-setstate-in-react-b837ceaf8304/

```js
import { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: true
    };
    this.Log = this.Log.bind(this);
  }

  Log = () => {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: !this.state.loggedIn });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.Log}>{`${this.state.loggedIn}`}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

You can use ES6 template literals like the above mentioned to log the state in the button.

https://codesandbox.io/s/setstate-in-render-68189771-4tzec?file=/src/App.js

Let me know if you need further support.

Answer (score 0):

I think try changing `loggedIn` to `this.state.loggedIn` might help

```js
const Log = () => {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: !this.state.loggedIn })
}
```

Comment: Now I don't receive any error messages, but still cannot see the value of the state in the button

Comment: I think it's because true, false can't be display in raw html. But if you use  `{String(this.state.loggedIn)}`  instead You will see its state in form of string